# Is it possible to use PDF.js as a standalone program?

Tags: firefox, pdf, pdf-reader

I really enjoy the PDF.js reader that comes with Firefox. However, I would like to use PDF.js as a standalone program, so that when I open a pdf file Firefox does not open. That way I can keep browsing separate from reading pdf files. Is this possible?

Comment: PDF.js is not a standalone application per se, it must be run in some kind of browser environment in order to handle the rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF.js is a web application, not a compiled application, and it requires a Java framework and some web browser components to function.

Here is a discussion on this very topic for more research: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.pdf-js/cDZwsFS1kio

Windows does offer a framework you may be able to leverage for this, but it would require compiling PDF.js into an HTML file, then renaming it to .hta.

The HTA file still calls Internet Explorer, but does so in a minimal framework that looks and behaves more like a regular application.

Then you'd have to find a way to call the individual PDFs or there would have to be a file browser included in the compiled product, and I'm just not sure how that would work.